# How can i add 2 summarized field in Cross-tab Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crosstab, crystal-reports-2010

I create report using cross tab in crystal report, I have columns as picture below. I want, 2 of summarized column (Qty and Sales) and added 2 of summarized field in cross-tab expert. But it's still not work.

If I want to assign value from #4 to #3.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crosstab expert - Customize style - Summarized fields - choose Horizontal, check Show Lables.

At least in my older CR (9.0) this works.

If this doesn't andswer your question then sorry - your question is somewhat badly worded.