# Cystal report multiple rows issue

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

How to make crystal report like this in visual studio 2010.

[image: how to create crystal report like this]

Comment: is there relation with these 3 record like part no

Comment: provide more infor like how database data looks like?

Comment: good question and also see my answer will help you.

Comment: I have not designed database, for me database is not important. Even it ll contain redundant data I don't mind. Just tell me how to make like this.

Comment: i given the answer for the same

Answer (score 1):

I do not know that my suggestion will work.

In any footer section, You can create a 2 cross-tab, then in first cross-tab add 2 column (Sr. no and Part Name) as above and in second cross-tab add 3 columns (Part no, Operation Description and CP no).

After check the data set both cross-tab as treat as a single cross-tab report.

You can hide/show the border.

You can check this (this will not exactly, but give the idea):

[How can i add 2 summarized field in Cross-tab Crystal Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377165/how-can-i-add-2-summarized-field-in-cross-tab-crystal-report)

http://flylib.com/books/en/4.229.1.71/1/